# Archive table implementation with Symfony 4 and Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I read about some arguments on Soft delete vs. Archive table which led me to this question.

I thought I could implement an entity Product which is mapped to two identical tables Product and ArchivedProduct, but [there is a known limitation of Doctrine 2](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#cascade-merge-with-bi-directional-associations)

> Mapping many tables to one entity
>   It is not possible to map several equally looking tables onto one entity. For example, if you have a production and an archive table of a certain business concept then you cannot have both tables map to the same entity.

So I thought I could use two entities, Product and ArchivedProduct, that are mapped to the same table, but it led to another problem that the One-to-Many reference $products in the entity Category should be mapped to two different entities.

Should I use Inheritance Mapping on Product and ArchivedProduct? What's the best practice of Archive table with Symfony 4 and Doctrine 2?

Comment: Could it help to use some flag in the existing product model to mark it as archived?

Comment: That's soft deletes which have a lot of problems. That's why I tried to use archive tables.

Comment: I have the same use case like your Product/ArchivedProduct. Any solution you found except soft-deleted or an `archived` flag?